# Transformation of data

Tags: r, data-transformation, partial-least-squares

I have a question regarding transformation of data. I have handled some data with both negative and positive elements by using the transformation:

log(Y+1-min(Y))

which is all good. The problem is though, that I am not sure when I should transform the data back.

I am using the data in a decomposition analysis using PLSR in R. Before applying the analysis I am calculating the cumulative change which I am using for the regression. Am I then supposed to transform the data back after the regression or before?

Hope my question makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why are you transforming at all?

Comment: Thank you! I thought because I have to calculate the cumulative changes that I would need to have the data in the natural log.
I think that I have learned that it is more accurate to calculate it when data is log-transformed. I might be remembering wrong though

Comment: Where did you see this transform recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this transformation mentioned in various places, but never with a detailed discussion of its advantages and limitations, in general or for the dataset being analyzed.  References to the contrary are most welcome. (The specific software or literature reference that led you here should be easy to cite.)

I guess the motive is noticing skewness in a distribution, thinking that is bad, and wanting to reduce it.

But, but, but:

1. If the aim is to reduce skewness, does that even work?
2. For most regression-type procedures, symmetric distributions for outcomes or predictors are not required. Very highly skewed distributions do often oblige a different analysis (e.g. use of logarithmic link) but mostly because such a functional form makes more sense any way.
3. Does the transformation help in other respects, for example, in getting closer to linearity or additivity?
4. The constant $1$ is a fudge, as otherwise $Y - \min(Y)$ has a minimum at $0$ and $\log 0$ is undefined. Any other positive constant would be another fudge, and what's  to choose between them?
5. If $\min(Y)$ is the empirical minimum, then it will be hard, and in some cases impossible, to compare results with those from any other similar datasets. Most often, the minimum in principle for a variable will be zero, in which case we have $\log(Y + 1)$ which does have some small virtues. It is highly desirable that analyses can be compared with those from similar data.
6. It's hard (for me) to think that the transformation has a helpful scientific or practical interpretation, especially if the minimum used is the empirical minimum.
7. Specifically here, if data can be negative, zero, or positive, then the origin should be respected unless it is completely arbitrary. Transformations that preserve sign such as cube root, $\text{sign}(Y) \log(1 + |Y|)$ or $\text{asinh}(Y)$ are other possibilities.

Transformations divide statistical opinion. I am quite positive about transformations compared with many active users here, but arbitrary transformations based on obscure reasoning do not help anyone much and may conceal as much as they reveal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
So, in your opinion then it would be best not to transform the data?

Comment: I didn't say that at all. I can't see your data and am fuzzy about your goals, so quite what is best for you is distinct from a general riff on that transformation.  "a decomposition analysis using PLSR" is not something I know about. From the sound of it, you are focusing on an outcome variable, so a minimum need is more detail about its distribution. How it plays with other variables is also important. (People who answer a lot are generally fairly experienced, but that doesn't make them oracles for telling you the best analysis for your problem.)

Comment: I see that. I have not given any information, so it is quite hard for you to answer that.


I am working with the dependent variable Brent Crude Oil. The goal of the analysis using PLSR is to see how much the explanatory variables "Inventory, FX EUR/USD and Oil Forward Curve" each explains a change in per cent of the dependent variable.

Therefore, I wanted to use a transformation on the data as changes in oil price and the explanatory is quite hard to pinpoint an exact distribution.

Comment: So, the outcome is really percent change in a price. That's about all I think I understand. I am not in economics or finance. What does a  quantile plot of the data look like?

Comment: The quantile plot of the (cumulative percent change) dependent variable and explanatory looks like:
https://imgur.com/a/xnhNnXc
It seems that there is an outlier in the 4th plot.

Comment: No; the fourth plot there shows a strong separation into groups, which is nothing to do with outliers.  But on this evidence I see no need to transform at all.

Comment: But why are you cumulating?

Comment: Okay, thank you. The reason that I am cumulating is that I want to recreate this graph:
https://imgur.com/a/FfUK00g

Comment: Again, on the evidence I see, there is no case for transforming.